# Negative reputation

Tags: support, reputation

Is this normal!?

[image]

Upon visiting the negative reputation profiles a positive reputation has been displayed.

---

About Opera
Version information
Version
11.10

Build
2092

Platform
Win32

System
Windows 7

Comment: You're looking at the monthly tab which shows the rep change this month. When you go to the user pages you get the user's current total rep or 1 whichever is the greater.

Comment: As Iain points out, that's rep change. A person's rep can't go negative, it stops at 1. Also, it isn't cumulative. If you start at 1, get a -6 for a bad question, then your next question is good and you get two upvotes (+10), your rep total will be 11.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that'll be bounties.

I definitely saw jldugger put a 500 bounty on [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/110964/can-i-get-ad-to-authenticate-via-another-ldap-server), and quickly clicking through some of the others, they look like bounties as well.

You can go on a users profile, go to the reputation page and click the huge negative bar in the chart and that will reveal a bounty was offered.